# C - Honestly at a loss for this odd behaviour

Tags: c

So... I have a little piece of code I have been working on for most of the morning. It's just a little project to help me remember syntax and so on. I have obviously missed some kind of massive error as the code returns a segmentation fault for reasons I don't understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <getopt.h>

struct cards 
{
int card_value[99];
char card_name[99];
char card_suit[99];
int card_tally;
};

struct cards hand[2];

void tally (int a)
{
int k, j;
for (k=0; k<5; k++)
 {
  j = j + hand[a].card_value[k];
 }
hand[a].card_tally = j;
 }

 void check_for_ace (int a)
 {
int d;
for (d=0; d>5; d++)
  { 
    if (hand[a].card_name[d] =='A')
      {
          int y;
          int z = 10;
          for (y=0; y<5; y++)
            z = z + hand[a].card_value[y];
          if (z < 22)
            hand[a].card_value[d]=10;
          else
            hand[a].card_value[d]=1;
      }

   }
}

void draw_card (int a)
{
int z = 1 + rand () % 13;
int x=0;

while (hand[a].card_value[x] !=  0)
    { x++; }

if ((z > 1) && (z < 10))
  {
      hand[a].card_value[x]=z;
      hand[a].card_name[x]=((char) '0' + z);
  }
else if (z == 10)
  {
      hand[a].card_value[x]=z;
      hand[a].card_name[x]='T';
  }
else if (z == 11)
  {
      hand[a].card_value[x]=10;
      hand[a].card_name[x]='J';
  }   
else if (z == 12)
  {
      hand[a].card_value[x]=10;
      hand[a].card_name[x]='Q';
  }
else if (z == 13)
  {
      hand[a].card_value[x]=10;
      hand[a].card_name[x]='K';
  }
else if (z == 1)
  {
      /*Function 'check_for_ace' deals with this more properly*/
      hand[a].card_value[x]=1;
      hand[a].card_name[x]='A';
  }
 check_for_ace(a);
 tally(a);
}



void display_hands ()
{
int x;
printf("\nDealer's Hand Shows: ");
for (x=0; hand[0].card_name[x]!=0; x++)
  {
      printf("%c ", hand[0].card_name[x]);
  }

printf("\nPlayer's Hand Shows: ");
for (x=0; hand[1].card_name[x]!=0; x++)
  {
      printf("%c ", hand[1].card_name[x]);
  }
}

void dealer_turn()
{
  while (hand[0].card_tally < 17)
  draw_card(0);
}

void player_turn()
{
int op=0;
while (op != 2)
  {
    printf("What would you like to do?\n");
    printf("(1)it or (2)tand\n");
    scanf("%d", &op); 
    if (op == 1)
     draw_card(1);

  }
}   

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
srand(time(NULL));


    draw_card(0);
    draw_card(1);
    draw_card(1);
    display_hands();
    player_turn();

    dealer_turn();
    display_hands();

return 0;
}
```

Now, the really odd thing is, see that empty line between player_turn and dealer_turn? If I put a display_hands in there the code executes without error.

Any ideas?

Also, I realize I did use headers I don't require. I plan to use them later and just left them in for this post so that I would have left everything exactly as it is with the error.

Comment: Read the compiler warnings!

Comment: Did you mean to include <stdio.h> twice? Shouldn't one be <stdlib.h>?

Comment: Armin: All I get is an implicit function declaration warning about rand but rand will return numbers in a loop until I get sick of seeing them without causing an error. Is there an error I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps this: `for (d=0; d>5; d++)`, in `check_for_ace()`? Actually, though, that shouldn't fault, it will just never run the loop body...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't initializing j before you execute this line.

```
  j = j + hand[a].card_value[k];
```

When I added a `j=0` initialization to your code, it no longer crashes.

E.g.

```
void tally (int a)
{
int k, j;
j=0;  /* <----- added this line */
for (k=0; k<5; k++)
 {
  j = j + hand[a].card_value[k];
 }
hand[a].card_tally = j;
 }
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct, that does in fact fix it. I thought that all declared but uninitialized integers started with a value of 0, for some reason. A mistake I will not be making again. Thank you, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Only the global-scope ones, but it's best not to rely on that either...

Comment: a simple habit that can save hours of debugging...