# Initialize a variable

Tags: c++, c, variables

Is it better to declare and initialize the variable or just declare it?
What's the best and the most efficient way?

For example, I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number = 0;

    printf("Enter with a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    if(number < 0)
        number= -number;

    printf("The modulo is: %d\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```

If I don't initialize `number`, the code works fine, but I want to know, is it faster, better, more efficient? Is it good to initialize the variable?

Comment: *more fast*? Do you care that much? How *fast* do you want your program to run?

Comment: Here we go. *Premature optimization* strikes again.

Comment: Do not write multi-language source files. It is hard work and more often than not the result isn't good in either of the intended languages.

Comment: Optimizer will take care of that and by premature optimization you can only make his work harder. Just write the code the way it is supposed to work and don't worry about the performance issues.

Comment: Unless you have a strong reason to avoid initialization, always using initialization (even when redundant) is a good methodology to follow.

Comment: Not only will not initializing the variable in this case not save any time you can measure (unless you're using a logic analyzer to count instructions -- and even then, it's likely your compiler removed the initialization for you), but additionally, you're calling absolute value "modulo", which is not valid.

Comment: You should always initialize your variables if you don't want to look like cat following its tail while debugging.

Comment: I'd care more about the fact you're reporting a modulo of a number as itself and the utter inaccuracies within that circus, or that you never check the result of your `scanf()` call to ensure the variable you're so worried about *not* initializing is, in fact actually *populated*. There are far more things to worry about than the speed of initializing a variable in this code.

Comment: initialize a variable when the variable is declared....i prefer it this way....this will also have benefit of not using uninitialized variable ever in progam

Answer (score 10):

`scanf` can fail, in which case nothing is written to `number`. So if you want your code to be *correct* you need to initialize it (or check the return value of `scanf`).

The speed of incorrect code is usually irrelevant, but for you example code if there is a difference in speed at all then I doubt you would ever be able to measure it. Setting an `int` to 0 is much faster than I/O.

Comment: I thought the contents of 'unassigned' variables are indeterminate.

Comment: @pmg: it's not clear what language this code is written in. In C++ it's UB to read an uninitialized variable. In C there's an indeterminate value, that can be read. Nevertheless I think I can say that it's "incorrect" to print for example "the modulo is: 5638044" when the user input was an empty line of text, but YMMV ;-)

Comment: As a sort of aside - if scanf fails, should it not throw an exception?

Comment: @MartinJames: no, it doesn't.

Comment: @MartinJames: `scanf` is a C function, no exceptions there... even most C++ standard libraries will avoid throwing exceptions unless you explicitly request it (i.e. `std::cin >> i;` won't throw either)

Comment: Yeah, @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I realize now that the scanf code has no idea whether it's called from C or some C++ with an exception-handler, so I was being a bit over-expectant :)

Comment: @SteveJessop, I don't get you, in this example if I press "kjlfkjdflsk" number is still equal to 0 (although not been initialized)

Comment: @DavidRF: just because you're seeing the value 0 doesn't mean it was `scanf` that put it there.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose if you don't  initialize a variable and your code is buggy.(e.g. you forgot to read number). Then uninitialized value of number is garbage and different run will output(or behave) different results.

But If you initialize all of your variables then it will produce constant result. An easy to trace error.

Yes, initialize steps will add extra steps in your code at low level. for example `mov $0, 28(%esp)` in your code at low level. But its one time task. doesn't kill your code efficiency.

So, always using **initialization is a good practice**!

Answer (score 3):

Don't attribute speed to language; That attribute belongs to implementations of language. There are fast implementations and slow implementations. There are optimisations assosciated with fast implementations; A compiler that produces well-optimised machine code would optimise the initialisation away if it can deduce that it doesn't need the initialisation.

In this case, it actually does need the initialisation. Consider if scanf were to fail. When scanf fails, it's return value reflects this failure. It'll either return:

1. A value less than zero if there was a read error or EOF (which can be triggered in an implementation-defined way, typically CTRL+Z on Windows and CTRL+d on Linux),
2. A number less than the number of objects provided to scanf (since you've provided only one object, this failure return value would be 0) when a conversion failure occurs (for example, entering 'a' on stdin when you've told scanf to convert sequences of '0'..'9' into an integer),
3. The number of objects scanf managed to assign to. This is 1, in your case.

Since you aren't checking for any of these return values (particular #3), your compiler can't deduce that the initialisation is necessary and hence, can't optimise it away. When the variable is uninitialised, failure to check these return values results in undefined behaviour. A chicken might appear to be living, even when it is missing its head. It would be best to check the return value of scanf. That way, when your variable is uninitialised you can avoid using an uninitialised value, and when it isn't your compiler can optimise away the initialisations, presuming you handle erroneous return values by producing error messages rather than using the variable.

edit: On that topic of undefined behaviour, consider what happens in this code:

```
if(number < 0)
    number= -number;
```

If number is -32768, and INT_MAX is 32767, then section 6.5, paragraph 5 of the C standard applies because -(-32768) isn't representable as an int.

Section 6.5, paragraph 5 says:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an
>   expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or
>   not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior
>   is undefined.

Comment: I didn't notice you answer, but you have good concept :)... what do you do? .. by chance I came back to this page.. nice answer specially fist few lines

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks. I'm a keen hobbyist programmer, with a dream to take over the world. Though I have worked in the industry, I prefer the freedom to consider my work as my own expression, rather than being told what to do and how to do it by an employer.

Comment: :) :D nice thoughts too :) .. anyways I would highly encourage you to keep writing and learning like this you have given many answer that is very good for new guys... your sentences are good...I would like to see your profile some time..:)..

Answer (score 1):

With modern compilers, there isn't going to be any difference in efficiency. Coding style is the main consideration. In general, your code is more self-explanatory and less likely to have mistakes if you initialize all variables upon declaring them. In the case you gave, though, since the variable is effectively initialized by the scanf, I'd consider it better not to have a redundant initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Before, you need to answer to this questions:

1) how many time is called this function? if you call 10.000.000 times, so, it's a good idea to have the best.

2) If I don't inizialize my variable, I'm sure that my code is safe and not throw any exception?

After, an int inizialization doesn't change so much in your code, but a string inizialization yes.

Be sure that you do all the controls, because if you have a not-inizialized variable your program is potentially buggy.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you how many times I've seen simple errors because a programmer doesn't initialize a variable. Just two days ago there was [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165601/c-honestly-at-a-loss-for-this-odd-behaviour) where the end result of the issue being faced was simply that the OP didn't initialize a variable and thus there were problems.

When you talk about "speed" and "efficiency" don't simply consider how much faster the code might compile or run (and in this case it's pretty much irrelevant anyway) but consider your *debugging* time when there's a simple mistake in the code do to the fact you *didn't* initialize a variable that very easily could have been.

Note also, my experience is when coding for larger corporations they will run your code through tools like [coverity](http://www.coverity.com/products/coverity-save-aw.html?gclid=CLDMqtKG47UCFQWEnQodXSEA-A) or [klocwork](http://www.klocwork.com/index-v2.php) which will ding you for uninitialized variables because they present a security risk.