# Appending character to a string in C with strcat

Tags: c++, c

Hi guys I'm still really confused with pointers and I'm wondering if there's anyways to do the following without having to use sprintf:

```
char a[100], b[100], c[2];

//Some code that puts a string into a 

for(i = 0; i<strlen(a); i++)
{
    if(a[i] == 'C')
        strcat(b, "b");
    else if(a[i] == 'O')
        strcat(b, "a");
    else if(a[i] == 'D')
        strcat(b, "1");
    else
    {
        sprintf(c, "%s", a[i]);
        strcat(b, c);
    }
}
```

pretty much a for loop looping through a string(an array) and filling up another string with a character(or string) depending on what the character is, if the character ain'T C, O or D it just adds it to the other string.

- I can't seem to just do `strcat(b, a[i]);` and I understand that it wouldn't work because it would try `strcat(char *, char)` instead of `char*, const char*)`.
  *Is there anyway I can turn it into a pointer?* they still confuse me so much..and I'm new to programming in general just to low level languages...
- also what would be *the best way to initialize `char[]`s?* that are gonna be filled with a string, what I use right now is :

  ```
  char ie[30] = ""
  ```
- Also let me know if there's any easier way to do what

I want and sorry if it's unclear this is obviously a throwaway script but the same concept is used in my script.

Thank you in advance stackoverflow :X

Comment: Consider pointers and a table that contains your translations. [See it live.](http://ideone.com/4HL343)

Comment: user2204015 post your question in good formate so that  one can easily understood your question.

Answer (score 2):

**(1)** One bug may be in your code:

You are commenting that *Some code that puts a string into a*, and I think you don't assign any string to `b`. so by default `char b[100];` have garbage value (may not present `\0` in `b`). but string concatenation function expects that `b` must be a string. So

```
strcat(b, "b");   <--will Undefined Behavior
```

**(2)** A technique to initialize empty string:

Yes you should always initialize you variable (array)  with default values like:

```
char a[100] = {0}, b[100] = {0}, c[2] = {0};
```

note: remaining elements of a half initialize array would be `0` (null), Initialize a [variable assume to be good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201276/initialize-a-variable)

**(3)** Yes `strcat(b, a[i]);` is wrong:

To concatenate string from `a[i]` on words into `b` you can do like:

```
strcat(b, a + i);
```

yes you are correct `strcat(b, a[i]);`  is not valid indeed.

note: `a[i]` and `(a + i)` are not same, `a[i]` is char type, where as `(a + i)` is string that is type of `a`.

Suppose you have following string array `a` and value of `i` is 2 then:

```
+----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+---+
| 'u'| 's' |'e'|'r'|'5'| '6'| '7'|'8' | 0 |  
+----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+---+
 201   202  203 204 205 206  207   208 209 210  211
  ^          ^  
  |          |
  a         (a+i)
```

So in above diagram `a` values is `201` and type is `char [100]` (assuming array is 100 in size)  `(a + i)`  also points a string from `'e'` at *address* `203`. where as `a[i] = 'e'`

So you can't do `strcat(b, a[i]);` but `strcat(b, a + i);` is valid syntax.

Additionally, From @BenVoigt to concat `n` chars from `a` from `i`th position you can do like:

```
strncat(b, a+i, n);
```

its will append `n` char from `a+i` to `b`.

Comment: A valid observation, but it doesn't answer his question, which is how to append one character instead of an entire NUL-terminated string.

Comment: @BenVoigt ok I read his  question again and try to improve my answer

Comment: @BenVoigt While we're on the topic of who posts incorrect comments on what... Doesn't your answer append more than one character?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Mine, or Grijesh's?  Mine appends at most one, that's what the `n` in `strncat` does.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: It lengthens the string by one.  `a[i]` replaces the existing NUL character, and then a new NUL character is added.  Or, you can think of it as *moving* the NUL character, I don't care.  Either way, the string is one character longer, and there is still a terminating NUL.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to take a substring of `a` exactly one character long:

```
strncat(b, a+i, 1);
```

Comment: @modifiablelvalue what is wrong in this? not underst00d to me  I think Ben Voigt is correct..

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Considering that `strncat` won't put a null terminator in b (unless a+i points directly at a null terminator), b won't be a string after this function returns. When the next iteration of the loop comes around, the same expression is evaluated, and bam! Undefined behaviour, of the same variety that the OP has.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue  read: [strncat: Appends the first num characters of source to destination, plus a terminating null-character](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I'll revoke my comments to make room here.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, nobody's perfect. You're quite easily amused (and sadistic, perhaps). Have a nice day.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue One should always take time before down-vote. Commenting is no problem.. actually because of  Ben I could improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize all char array to null so that no garbage values exists in code.

You are appending to garbaged char array.

```
char a[100]={0}, b[100]={0}, c[2]={0};
```

Now strcat() function behaves properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to do as you wish.  There are ways that avoid using `strcat()` and `sprintf()` altogether — see below; you can avoid `sprintf()` while continuing to use `strcat()`.

The way I'd probably do it would keep a record of where the next character is to be added to the target string, `b`.  This will be more efficient since repeatedly using `strcat()` involves quadratic behaviour as you build up a string one character at a time.  Also, it is generally best to avoid using `strlen()` in the loop condition for the same reason; it is (probably) evaluated on each iteration, so that it too leads to quadratic behaviour.

```
char a[100], b[100];
char *bp = b;

//Some code that puts a string into a 
size_t len = strlen(a);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++, bp++)
{
    if (a[i] == 'C')
        *bp = 'b';
    else if(a[i] == 'O')
        *bp = 'a';
    else if(a[i] == 'D')
        *bp = '1';
    else
        *bp = a[i];
}
*bp = '\0';   // Null-terminate the string
```

You could also do without the pointer by using the index variable `i` to assign to `b` (as long as you only add one character to the output for each input character):

```
char a[100], b[100];

//Some code that puts a string into a 
size_t len = strlen(a);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (a[i] == 'C')
        b[i] = 'b';
    else if(a[i] == 'O')
        b[i] = 'a';
    else if(a[i] == 'D')
        b[i] = '1';
    else
        b[i] = a[i];
}
b[i] = '\0';   // Null-terminate the string
```

As long as the string in `a` is short enough to fit, the code shown (either version) cannot overflow `b`.  If you sometimes added several characters to `b`, you'd either need to indexes (`i` and `j`), or you could increment the pointer `bp` in the first version more than once per loop, and you'd need to ensure that you don't overflow the bounds of `b`.

Comment: If the implementation can prove that the length of the string contained in `a` doesn't change, then it can make the same optimisation that you have made manually.

Comment: Yes, but that's a pretty big ***if***.

Comment: @jonathanLeffler: You're right. There is no point postulating on what behaviour the implementation *might* produce from this code... That's irrelevant to this question. So my question, now, is: Why postulate?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: I'm not sure what you're trying to get at?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You can't dismiss the possibility that an implementation *might* perform optimisations, if you're not prepared to dismiss the possibility that an implementation *might not* perform optimisations. Have you studied the optimisations that compilers make, now-a-days? Furthermore, the behaviour of that loop is irrelevant to this question. That's all I'm going to say, here, in order to avoid getting into a lengthy, pointless discussion like my last one with Ben Voigt :/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused in regards to *strings*. A string isn't just an array. Which book are you reading?

When you first call `strcat` to operate on `b`, `b` isn't guaranteed to be a string. The result is undefined behaviour. This code might seem to function correctly on your system, but if it does then that is by coincidence. I have seen code like this fail in strange ways on other systems. Fix it like this:

```
char a[100], b[100];

//Some code that puts a string into a
a[x] = '\0'; // <--- Null terminator is required for a to contain a "string".
             //      Otherwise, you can't pass a to strlen.

for(i = 0; i<strlen(a); i++)
{
    if(a[i] == 'C')
        b[i] = 'b';
    else if(a[i] == 'O')
        b[i] = 'a';
    else if(a[i] == 'D')
        b[i] = '1';
    else
        b[i] = a[i];
}

b[i] = '\0'; // If you don't put a null character at the end, it isn't a string.
```

Now, what is a string?

Comment: lol, duh (and other sick donkey noises). I meant `a[i]`. Thanks :)

Comment: The 'some code that puts a string into `a`' must include a null terminator; it isn't a string if it doesn't have a null terminator.  If you know `x`, you don't need `strlen(a)`, whether it gets optimized or not.

Comment: Indeed, though the focus of my answer was to educate the OP as to the true definition of *string*. I may be asking a question pertaining to optimisations and other algorithms used to produce the behaviour of a C program. I'm at the stage of thinking about how to make it fit into the SO guidelines, so it doesn't get closed off. I hope to see you there :)